# Default constructor is deprecated, I can't find the fragment problem in Adroid Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

When I write the Code like this, the ControlFragment works fine, but when I use the exact same Code in my other Fragment named "AndresFragment" (second code), it's not working. It says "Default constructor in android.app.Fragment is deprecated". I really don't get it... Can someone please help me, I'm new in

```
package com.example.fragm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class ControlFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        }
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.controlfragment,
                container, false);
        return myView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

}
```

Code for "AndresFragment":

```
package com.example.fragm;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AndresFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
// restore internal values if necessary
        }
        View myView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.andresfragment,
                container, false);
        return myView1;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

That's my Mainactivity.java with the ControlFragment it works:

```
package com.example.fragm;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        ControlFragment myFragment = new ControlFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.my_fragment_container, myFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

But I can't use "AndresFragment"

```
package com.example.fragm;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        AndresFragment myFragment = new AndresFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.my_fragment_container, myFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, the error is: "error: no suitable method found for add(int,AndresFragment)
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.my_fragment_container, myFragment).commit();"

Comment: both files use different `Fragment` base classes: `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;` in one and `import android.app.Fragment;` in other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have wrong import in your `AndresFragment`.

Instead of:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

You should use:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

In your first file you have proper import and that is why you don't have error there, `android.app.Fragment` is old and deprecated so that is why you receive error message since you should be using new one.

Comment: i searched for an hour why it wasn't working and in the end this answer worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this:

[image]

just invalidate caches and restart